# Ng-if to show and hide td data

Tags: angularjs, datatables

Attached is my code, tried showing td data when the condtion of ng-if is true

```
 <tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="fellow in fellowships">
   <td>{{$index}}</td>
   <td>{{fellow.Fellowship_Name}}</td>
   <div ng-repeat="value in data_report"
        ng-if="(fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id)? (show_row = true) : (show_row=false)">

     <td ng-show="show_row">{{value.Completed}}</td>
     <td ng-hide="show_row">0</td>

     <td ng-show="show_row">{{value.Not_Updated}}</td>
     <td ng-hide="show_row">0</td>

     <td ng-show="show_row">{{value.Total_schedule}}</td>
     <td ng-hide="show_row">0</td>
   </div>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Its just giving 0 as result. Though data_report is having values
Tried adding span in td with conditions in td and result in span.
still the result is zero

May I know where the logic is going wrong and how it can be achieved?

Changed the code to

```
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="fellow in fellowships">
    <td>{{$index}}</td>
    <td>{{fellow.Fellowship_Name}}</td>

    <td>
    <span ng-repeat="value in data_report" ng-show ="fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id">{{value.Completed}}</span>
    </td>

    <td>
    <span ng-repeat="value in data_report" ng-show="fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id">{{value.Not_Updated}}</span>
    </td>

    <td>
   <span ng-repeat="value in data_report" ng-show="fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id">{{value.Total_schedule}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Here i am getting values but how can i set default value to zero if there are no values present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `ng-if` returns no boolean

The usage is ([DOCs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)):

```
<ANY
  ng-if="expression">
...
</ANY>
```

---

I think you dont need `ng-if` at all. You can write something like:

```
 <tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="fellow in fellowships">
   <td>{{$index}}</td>
   <td>{{fellow.Fellowship_Name}}</td>
   <div ng-repeat="value in data_report">
     <td>{{(fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id) ? value.Completed: 0}}</td>
     <td>{{(fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id) ? value.Not_Updated: 0}}</td>
     <td>{{(fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id) ? value.Total_schedule: 0}}</td>

   </div>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Its not best solution, in Javascript you can set for example `value.Completed` to be by default `0`. It will help you to simplify your HTML

Comment: How can it be set from javascript?

Comment: fellowships and data_report are both fetched from two different databases.

Comment: Its still giving zero value

Comment: <td>                                                                                                        <span ng-show="fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id">{{value.Completed}}</span><span ng-hide="fellow.F_Id==value.fellowship_id">0</span>    </td>                                                                                                      Tried this also yet the value is 0

Comment: @PoojaBajajDhoot you can try to print actual value by writing `<pre>{{value |json}}</pre>`. Check what you have inside `value`

Comment: I have data coming from table in that value.. i have printed it on tbody tocheck the variable data as {{data_report}}

Comment: @PoojaBajajDhoot please post JSON data into `data_report `. thanks

Comment: its json data only. i have made some changes in code. I am getting the result, but extra columns are getting added, how can i check the value is for that particular column?